# Python3 and Robot Framework b'SUCCESS' Error

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

Currently experimenting (or trying to) with Robot Framework. I'm using Python-3 and I've managed to get a version of the framework for python 3.

```
pip install robotframework-python3
```

I downloaded the QuickStart guide which was recommended on the [GitHub](https://github.com/robotframework/QuickStartGuide/blob/master/QuickStart.rst) page and I had to convert some of it from Python2 to Python 3. This just included to minor changes, removing commas from try/except and a few brackets around prints. This ran the first test of tests wonderfully.
When it came to running the other tests with the command:

```
pybot QuickStart.rst
```

I had this error in the .html error logs it produces:

```
Expected status to be 'SUCCESS' but was 'b'SUCCESS''.
```

This error was common across all of the tests. I understand that it's related to a binary response (vague guess from memory).

Does anybody know of a solution?

N.B Robot Framework 2.8.7 (Python 3.3.3 on darwin)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also did the same thing as you and encountered the issue.
Apart from modifying the `sut/QuickStart.rst`, you may also need to modify the `lib/LoginLibrary.py` to append one more parameter, i.e. `universal_newlines=True` to `subprocess.Popen(...)` such that it will be treated as string instead of byte sequence. The `QuickStart.rst` test cases all pass now :)

You may check the reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen